# Apache Maven is not configured properly into System vairable

Tags: maven, maven-3, appium

I have latest version of Apache Maven 3.3.9 residing in my drive downloaded from [here](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi). I need it for configuring **Appium tool** to perform automated testing of Android applications. I have Maven plugin already configured with my **Eclipse** IDE. I went through few articles and got to know that I have to configure Maven into system variables as well. I set system variables, path for it as below.

```
M2HOME = C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache\apache-maven-3.3.9

M2 = %M2HOME%\bin

path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin;%M2%
```

I tried running `mvn` , `mvn -version` from cmd prompt to check successful configuration of Maven but it gave me nothing. I tried navigating to the bin folder and re run the command but still the result is same. I even changed my path variable to have absolute path of Apache Maven i.e `path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin`

To be further sure I copied the Apache Maven to a different folder just because it had spaces in between **Program Files** and **Program Files (x86)** but still the command prompt is as below:

[image]

I had followed above steps referring various articles in google. I'm not getting if I have committed any unseen mistake.

**P.S:** I have even tried above commands with **cmd** running as an administrator

Answer (score 0):

Try `mvn --version` (with two dashes). `mvn -v` should also work. If Maven is not being executed at all, I suggest you try `mvn.bat`.

Some Command Prompt configurations will refuse to run `.bat`-files without the extension unless you explicitly tell them to.

It's probably a good idea to run `where mvn` in your Command Prompt as well. You should get this:

```
<YOUR_MAVEN_HOME>\bin\mvn
<YOUR_MAVEN_HOME>\bin\mvn.bat
<YOUR_MAVEN_HOME>\bin\mvn.cmd
```

if everything it set up correctly.

Comment: I tried `mvn.bat` it threw _not recognised as internal or external command_ error. I also tried `where mvn`. It gave me result as `<MY_MAVEN_HOME>\bin\mvn` and `<MY_MAVEN_HOME>\bin\mvn.cmd`. It didn't returned `<MY_MAVEN_HOME>\bin\mvn.bat`

Comment: It's probably because of your `PATHEXT` environment variable. Try doing `set PATHEXT=%PATHEXT%;.BAT` and it should pop up.

Comment: I should do `set PATHEXT=%PATHEXT%;.BAT` in cmd? I did it but doesn't show anything. However I checked my `PATHEXT` and it has got `.BAT` along with other parameters

Comment: Strange. Did `<MY_MAVEN_HOME>\bin\mvn.bat` show up during a `where ...` after the pathext change?

Comment: Actually in the latest releases post 3.3.1 they've changed the extension of `mvn.bat` to `mvn.cmd`. so if there is older version of Maven it displays`mvn.bat` but on newest releases it gets `mvn.cmd`. But as I already said to @user299702 I'm using older version of Maven now  which seems to have done the trick with system and path variables. But will keep an active eye on current issue

Comment: Ok, as long as it's working out for you. I am using 3.3.9 and it's working without a hitch.

Comment: Thanks @Daneil for your suggestions. I'll double check with it and update if it works well

Answer (score 0):

- You should define `M2_HOME` variable. (Not M2HOME). Make sure it looks like this:
  [image]
- You said that you copied your maven to the location without spaces. That's a good idea. But it looks like your `Path` system variable points to the old location of maven. Make sure to change it. (What is the current location of maven?)
  [image]

BTW `mvn -version` works as well as `mvn --version`

Comment: thanks for the answer but there's no difference, be it `M2HOME` or `M2_HOME`. It's just naming. But we've to make sure the same is used every where else. 

And When I copied Maven files to a folder location without spaces I correspondingly edited my path and system variables too. I tried the same with older versions of Maven and have found to work. It's specifically not working with 3.9.9